# Linq Group by in lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have `Model` follow list:

```
    Id                  Name
----------------------------------------------------
    1                   john
    1                   john
    1                   john
    2                   jennifer
    2                   jennifer
    3                   smith
```

I want to group that `Model` to show following result

```
    Id                  Name
----------------------------------------------------
    1                   john
    2                   jennifer
    3                   smith
```

Answer (score 3):

If `Model` implements [`IEquatable<Model>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx) then it's trivial:

```
var noDuplicates = list.Distinct();
```

If it does not make sense for `Model` to implement that interface, you can use [this overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx) of `Distinct` that lets you specify the equality criteria on the side. The documentation for [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) has an example on how to implement such.

Answer (score 0):

```
                ILookup<int, string> lookup =
                list
                .ToLookup(p => p.Id,
                          p => p.Name);

            foreach (IGrouping<int, string> group in lookup)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(group.Key);
                foreach (string name in group)
                    Console.WriteLine("    {0}", name);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

from v in Model 
group v by v.id into g
select g

Comment: @Morteza.. thanks for your answer but make sure when answer have single line or less then it should be a comment,hope you got me :)